# How to update existing model instance from dictionary value

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

Given the model instance, for example StackOverflow is the model,
and

```
 obj = StackOverflow.objects.get(..somecondition)
 dict  = { 'rating' : 3, 'field1' : 'question', field2 : 'answer' }
```

StackOverflow model has all the keys that are available int the dict as a member variable.

I want to update obj with dict values.

How can i achieve the same?

Answer (score 10):

```
obj = StackOverflow.objects.get(pk=1)
d  = { 'rating' : 3, 'field1' : 'question', 'field2' : 'answer' }

for i in d:
    setattr(obj, i, d[i])
obj.save()
```

This will work, assuming the dictionary keys correspond to fields in the `StackOverflow` model, and the dictionary values are valid field values.

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
d  = { 'rating' : 3, 'field1' : 'question', 'field2' : 'answer' }
obj = StackOverflow.objects.filter(pk=1).update(**d)
```

Here is the  [doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#update)